# How to combine arrays which are contained in a list in python

Tags: python, arrays

If I have something like;

```
a=np.array([1,2])
b=np.array([1,4])
c=[]
```

Firstly, what is the built in python function to enable the combination of a and b so that we have `array([1,2],[1,4])`

Also another question just for future reference, in the past ended up with things like `[array([1,2]), array([1,4])]` I wasn't sure what to do so I just had to redo the code. Is it bad practise to end up with a result like this or is there a function which can change this to `array([1,2],[1,4])` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See numpy [vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack) function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2])
>>> b = np.array([3, 4])
>>> np.vstack((a, b))
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into np.concatenate

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = np.array([[5, 6]])
>>> np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html